# Serializing filenames in a directory to JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json, spring

In a Spring 3 webapp, what would be the lowest dependency cost way to grab a list of filenames and serialize them to a JSON object to be passed to a JSP tree component in a view?

My conundrum is that:

1. As there is no other need for JSON processing in the app, I'm reluctant to add Jackson or the like for this one piece, it seems like overkill.
2. Rolling my own is easy, but I'm slightly allergic to rehashing work that has to have been done a thousand times already.

Any thoughts on a happy middle-ground?

Comment: `jackson` is like 500KB total... Just use it. `Gson` might be even smaller.

Comment: If all this is is an array of strings, then rolling your own is simple and not particularly distasteful.  Just a leading `[`, generate the names in "quotes", separate with commas, and close with `]`.  Of course, with a JSON toolkit it would be even more trivial -- create an array of the names and serialize it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I once wrote a JSON serializer for Qt in about 250 lines of code, and the parser in about 500.  I would *hope* that there are kits that are smaller.

Comment: Using Spring the best way for you to have Json is with Jackson!

Comment: Thanks SotrinosDelimanolis and @HotLicks. I wrote the code, and it's 27 lines long, with the helper to stringify the resource stream. If there's not a corner of the Java API I'm missing, it seems this is the way to go. Lean and mean.